# Insert new points into an existing grob in R

Tags: r, graphics

Suppose I have generated a grob like this:

```
require(grid)
x = 1:10
y = rnorm(10)
plotvp = plotViewport(c(5, 5, 3, 3), name='plotvp')
datavp = dataViewport(x, y, name='datavp')
datapts = pointsGrob(x, y, pch=20, size=unit(1.3, 'mm'), name='datapts')
xaxis = xaxisGrob()
yaxis = yaxisGrob()
xlab = textGrob('X Label', y=unit(-3, 'lines'), name='xlab')
ylab = textGrob('Y Label', x=unit(-3, 'lines'), rot=90, name='ylab')
plotbox = rectGrob()
dataplot = gTree(children=gList(datapts,
                                xaxis, yaxis,
                                xlab, ylab,
                                plotbox),
                 vp=datavp, name='dataplot')
wholeplot = gTree(children=gList(dataplot),
                  vp=plotvp, name='wholeplot')
```

Now I want to insert a new set of points:

```
x = 1:10
y = rnorm(10)
```

into the `wholeplot` grob, how can I do it?

According to @DWin 's answer, I did the following:

```
x=1:10
y=rnorm(10)
datapts2 <- pointsGrob(x, y, pch=15, size=unit(1.3, 'mm'), name='datapts2')
wholeplot <- addGrob(wholeplot, datapts2)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(wholeplot)
system('sleep 1')

datapts2 <- pointsGrob(x, y, pch=15, size=unit(1.3, 'mm'), name='datapts2')
wholeplot <- gTree(children=gList(dataplot, datapts2), vp=plotvp, name='wholeplot')
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(wholeplot)
system('sleep 1')
```

I didn't see any effect.

---

After some trial and error, I realized I need specify a viewport for the new data points:

```
x=1:10
y=rnorm(10)
datapts2 <- pointsGrob(
                       x, y, default.units='native', 
                       pch=15, size=unit(1.3, 'mm'), name='datapts2', 
                       vp=datavp
                       )
wholeplot <- addGrob(wholeplot, datapts2)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(wholeplot)
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
datapts2 <- pointsGrob(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10), pch=20, 
                       size=unit(1.3, 'mm'), name='datapts2')
?gTree
wholeplot <- addGrob(wholeplot, datapts)
```

You could also rebuild the `wholeplot` object I suppose.  The second points-grob is not in the "children" list. Doin it that way instead looks pretty much the same to me:

```
wholeplot = gTree(children=gList(dataplot, datapts2),
                   vp=plotvp, name='wholeplot')
str(wholeplot)
```

Comment: It should be `wholeplot <- addGrob(wholeplot, datapts2)` one the fourth line. The code runs without an error, but the result of `grid.draw(wholeplot)` does not show any difference than before.